# Mincha torah reading before a chag

Tags: halacha, shabbat, torah-reading, chagim-holidays, mincha-afternoon-prayer

What Torah reading should be read the Shabbat afternoon before a holiday, like the Shabbat afternoon before Sukkot, or the Shabbat afternoon before Rosh Hashanah or Yom Kippur?

Thanks..

Answer (score 7):

Shulchan Arukh OC 292:1

> במנחה אומרים אשרי ובא לציון ואני תפלתי וגו' ומוציאין ספר תורה וקורין ג' אנשים י' פסוקים מפרשה הבאה ואפילו חל יום טוב להיות בשבת קורין בפרשה הבאה ולא בשל יום טוב.
>   At Mincha one recites Ashrei ... and takes out a Torah scroll and three people read 10 verses (in total) from the next Parsha, and even if a holiday falls On Shabbat, they read from the next Parsha not the one from the holiday.

Comment: The halacha is right of course, but I'm not sure I agree with the translation.  I think it means "and even if a holiday falls on Shabbos".  That's my first instinct and it's also how the MB interprets it.

Comment: @Heshy You are right. I've edited the correct translation.

Comment: With the exception, of course, that when Yom Kippur falls on Shabbos (it is "a holiday"), then Vayikra (Leviticus) 18 is read instead.